# Android ICS (4.0) WebView touch events

Tags: android, webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Something weird popped up with one of my apps.
It seems, that with new version, webview stopped handling touch events continuously and instead waits for user to remove his finger from screen and only then does any actual handling of events (or rendering).

To put it simple, in pre 4.0 versions (don't know about 3.0) when user does something on screen (like scaling, or swiping) it is immediately displayed, in ICS webview will display changes only when user removes his fingers.

Did anyone encounter something like that? And how to beat that thing?

Comment: You mean UI or now frozen until the user lift its finger of the screen ?